# VBA XMLHTTP clear authentication?

Tags: vba, xmlhttprequest

I am writing a set of VBA macros in which it uses the XMLHTTP object to send asynchronous requests to a server.  I am sending Basic Authentication with:

```
XMLHttpReq.setRequestHeader "Authorization","Basic " & Base64EncodedUserPass
```

This works great the first time.
But if the user changes their userid/password, even if the code creates a brand new XMLHttpReq object and sets this header to the new information, it logs in to the server as the first user, presumably from cached credentials.

How can I cause the code to "forget" that I have logged in before, and re-authorize?

**Edit** as requested, the relevant part of the code; it really isn't very complicated:

```
myURL = "http://my.domain.com/myscript.cgi"
Dim oHttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
oHttp.Open "POST", myURL, False
oHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded'"
oHttp.setRequestHeader "Authorization","Basic " & Base64EncodedUsernamePassword
oHttp.send "PostArg1=PostArg1Value"
Result = oHttp.responseText
```

Comment: If i use the URL format http[s]://user:password@host/ then I can interchangeably use different usernames, but this seems less secure somehow. Maybe this is the only way to do it, though?

Comment: Did you try clearing out IE history? http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?440162-How-do-I-clear-Internet-Explorer-with-Excel-VBA

Comment: I don't want to clear out the entire IE history just for this one task. The underlying macros will be distributed to customers as part of a larger product, and I don't feel like I should be taking that much direct control over their IE cache.

Comment: OK. Can you show more of your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These questions have been discussed in many ways due to major browsers different implementations of caching methods.

I will give you what worked for me and then the sources I found on this *feature*.

The only solution I could came across was to force the browser to not cache the request.

```
myURL = "http://my.domain.com/myscript.cgi"
Dim oHttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
oHttp.Open "POST", myURL, False
oHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded'"
oHttp.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
oHttp.setRequestHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
oHttp.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");
oHttp.setRequestHeader "Authorization","Basic " & Base64EncodedUsernamePassword
oHttp.send "PostArg1=PostArg1Value"
Result = oHttp.responseText
```

It seems that `Cache-Control` works on most browsers and `Pragma` only on Firefox and not IE (don't know why...)

`If-Modified-Since` is used for IE, since IE uses different settings in his own algorithm to determine whether or not the request should be cached. XMLHttpRequest seem to not be treated as the same as HTTP responses.

**Careful** : With this code you will **need** `username` and `password` each time a new object is created. Maybe you should create a new object, instantiate it once and then destroy it after use. In between you would have all your requests handled in different functions with only one authentication.

---

### Sources

[MSDN setRequestHeader Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms766589(v=vs.85).aspx)

[MSDN IXMLHTTPRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms759148(v=vs.85).aspx)

[XMLHTTPREQUEST CACHING TESTS](http://www.mnot.net/javascript/xmlhttprequest/cache.html)

[XMLHttpRequest and Caching](http://www.subbu.org/blog/2005/10/xmlhttprequest-and-caching)

Comment: The only browser I need to worry about is IE in this case, because I am using the MSXML2.XMLHTTP object which (as far as I know) only uses the IE engine. I will give this a try.

Comment: On first examination, this did what I needed, but I may need to investigate more.  I am not quite ready to give this the "best answer" flag.

Comment: I am still marking this "best answer" because it partially works.  The remaining problem arises if an incorrect userid and password are sent in the Authentication header which causes the IE "username/password" popup window. If I enter a proper userid and password here manually, then the Authentication header is still ignored on later calls.  Any ideas?