# VBA XMLHTTP disable authentication pop-up

Tags: vba, excel, authentication

With reference to this question [VBA XMLHTTP clear authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526810/vba-xmlhttp-clear-authentication) I am also trying to pass basic authentication in VBA. It works perfectly.

My only concern is login pop up which comes up whenever a wrong userid or password is sent in request. Is there a way to disable this and send a message box to user from VBA itself telling him about authentication failure?

Update

VBA code:

```
Dim objHTTP As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

With objHTTP

    .Open "GET", UrlUserService, False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
    .setRequestHeader "Cache-Control", "no-cache"
    .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " + Base64Encode(userName + ":" + userPwd)
    .setRequestHeader "Pragma", "no-cache"
    .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
    .send ""
    response = .Status

End With
```

Popup
[image]

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve] please? To me it is unclear how this popup looks like.

Comment: Done, not able to upload image so added URL from MSDN, its basically windows security pop-up

Comment: You can test if `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` then write your code and `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` at the end suppresses this alert.

Comment: Nope, that didn't worked.

Comment: Use `Dim objHTTP As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60` to avoid the popup, then you can check `.Status`. If 401 authentication has failed. Don't ask me about the diff to `XMLHTTP60`, I have not found a good explanation yet, but if I do and this works for you I will post this as answer.

Comment: @BitAccesser Yes, you are right. Using `ServerXMLHTTP60` didn't show any popup. Also if I use `.Open "GET", UrlUserService, False, userName,userPwd` pop-up won't come

Answer (score 2):

Use Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0 protocol and pass the credentials as part of request

.Open "GET", pUrl, false, "pUsername", "pPassword"

Comment: Edit your question and be more specific. Otherwise, this can be a comment instead of an answer. thanks.