# Authorization data saved in xmlhttprequest with VBA

Tags: vba, xmlhttprequest

I am calling a Webservice with basic authentication with VBA. The problem I have is that the user/password is stored after the first successful call. That means I can put wrong user/password in the next calls and it works just the same.

```
Set objRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
blnAsync = True
With objRequest
    .Open "GET", strUrl, blnAsync
    .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " + EncodeBase64(user + ":" + passw)
    .Send
    'spin wheels whilst waiting for response
    While objRequest.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend
    strResponse = .responseText
End With
```

If I call the Webservice from browser it is the same. First time I need to login, next time it works without login. After I delete cache/cookies/history I need to login again.

My questions:

- Where is this (cache?) data stored if I call from VBA and how to delete this?
- How to prevent VBA from saving the authorization data?

Answer (score 1):

I found the crucial hint to put user/password in the .Open-method here: [VBA XMLHTTP disable authentication pop-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46114829/vba-xmlhttp-disable-authentication-pop-up)

That's how it works for me. The only thing I can't do now is encoding the user & password.

```
Dim objRequest As MSXML2.XMLHTTP30
Set objRequest = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP30

With objRequest
    .Open "GET", strUrl, blnAsync, user, passw
    .setRequestHeader "Cache-Control", "no-cache"
    .setRequestHeader "Pragma", "no-cache"
    .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
    While objRequest.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend
    strResponse = .responseText
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

To stop the caching, you could try adding:

```
.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
.setRequestHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");
```

See also [VBA XMLHTTP clear authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526810/vba-xmlhttp-clear-authentication) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. It is the same behavior as in your linked item. The solution works, if the authentication data is sent in the code. If the data is wrong or not sent, a login popup appears. If I use this popup the user/password is stored for the next webservice calls. I want to prevent that this popup comes up...